# ¿Cómo hago para redireccionar a una página cuando doy click en una etiqueta a, y dicha etiqueta está dentro de una tabla?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Quisiera saber el método para que al dar click en una etiqueta `<a>` me redireccione a otra página, JS ya está respondiendo al evento `onclick` que le mando, pero debido a que esta etiqueta se encuentra dentro de una tabla, parece que no hace nada cuando quiero usar la sentencia `window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/';`

Si alguien me puede ayudar, se lo agradezco.

```
<table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>NOMBRE</th>
                            <th>TIPO DOCUMENTO</th>
                            <th>NÚMERO DE DOCUMENTO</th>
                            <th>FECHA DE EXPEDICIÓN</th>
                            <th>PROFESIÓN</th>
                            <th>GÉNERO</th>
                            <th>FECHA DE NACIMIENTO</th>
                            <th>TIPO DE SANGRE</th>
                            <th>TELÉFONO</th>
                            <th>CORREO</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Pepe</td>
                        <td>CC</td>
                        <td>1234</td>
                        <td>12/03/2001</td>
                        <td>Médico</td>
                        <td>M</td>
                        <td>12/03/1994</td>
                        <td>O+</td>
                        <td>3213343432</td>
                        <td>aa@gmail.com</td>
                        <td><a onclick="return sendDataCustoms();" href="" id="button-update-client" class="col-10">Editar información</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendDataCustoms(){
        alert("Envío de datos");
        window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno primeramente no necesitas poner el return y segundo seria bueno que utilices `preventDefault()` para que la etiqueta `a` no realice el metodo por default cuando se le hace click, tu codigo quedaria asi:

```
function sendDataCustoms(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location = 'https://www.google.com';
}
```

y en el HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick='sendDataCustoms(event)'>Editar información</a>
```

Espero te sirva ;) Saludos

Answer (score 0):

El error es por que la etiqueta "a" no se està considerando como una ancla, lo que tienes que hacer es poner un valor a su atributo "href". Algo asi

```
<td><a onclick="return sendDataCustoms();" href="#" id="button-update-client" class="col-10">Editar información</a></td>
```

Y ya debería funcioanar.